# UITableView discloure indicator going nuts

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UITableView (on a UIViewController) which is pushed via a navigationController. Along with pushing, I select with which array i want to populate the table. The code for pushing is like this:

```
if(self.newView == nil)
{
    NewView *viewTwo = [[NewView alloc] initWithNibName:@"Bundle" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self.newView = viewTwo;
    [viewTwo release];
}

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.newView animated:YES];
newView.tableArray=newView.arrayWithOptionOne;
[newView.tableView reloadData];
```

All works well and the table gets reloaded every time. However in the last row of section 0, there is a switch which loads section 1.
The last row of section 1 is tappable (didSelect…) and it loads a modalView. On this last rod I added a disclosure indicator and also the blue background when tapping. The table has sliders, labels, etc. So the customization is quite long:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *cell = nil;


static NSString *kDisplayCell_ID = @"DisplayCellID";

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kDisplayCell_ID];

if (cell == nil)
    {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:kDisplayCell_ID] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    }
else
    {

    UIView *viewToRemove = nil;
    viewToRemove = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    if (viewToRemove)
        [viewToRemove removeFromSuperview];

    UIView *viewToRemove2 = nil;
    viewToRemove2 = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    if (viewToRemove2)
        [viewToRemove2 removeFromSuperview];


 }


    if (indexPath.section==0) {
        UIControl *cellValueS = [[[arrayTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:kViewKey] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cellValueS];
    }

    if (indexPath.section==0 && indexPath.row==3) {
        UIControl *cellValueL = [[[arrayTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:kViewLabel] objectAtIndex:0] ;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cellValueL];
    }

    if (indexPath.section==1 && indexPath.row==0){
        UIControl *cellValueS = [[[arrayTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:kViewKey] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cellValueS];
    } 

    if (indexPath.section==1 && indexPath.row==1) {
        UIControl *cellValueS = [[[arrayTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:kViewKey] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cellValueS];

        UIControl *cellValueL = [[[arrayTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:kViewLabel] objectAtIndex:0] ;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cellValueL];
    }

    if (indexPath.section==1 && indexPath.row==2) {
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

So far also works ok.

The problem is that when I go back to the previous view and select another option to populate the table, when it's pushed again, I see the disclosure   indicator and blue selection background on other rows on the same section. I've observed that it depends on where the table is scrolled.

I've tried to understand why does it happen, but i can't. I've somehow solved the problem by setting newView to nil and releasing it and then allocating it again before it gets pushed again.

Am I doing something wrong here? or why is the disclosure indicator and tapping background appearing where they are not supposed to be?

Thanks in advance!

action of the switch

```
-(void)extraOptionsSwitchAction:(id)sender{



 switch(extraOptionsSwitch.isOn) {

 case 1:

 // [self.tableView beginUpdates];
 [self.tableView insertSections: [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1]  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
 [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

 //[self.tableView reloadData];
 //  [self.tableView endUpdates];

 break;

 case !1:

 //   [self.tableView beginUpdates];
 [self.tableView deleteSections: [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1]  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
 // [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

 [self.tableView reloadData];
 // [self.tableView endUpdates];

 break;

 }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to to with reusing cells. You probably don't differentiate between the different cell types in your cell creation method - so one cell that went offscreen can easily be reused for another (different type) cell. Further, you seem to add subviews over and over again - only do that when you instantiate the cell (with alloc/int), and not when configuring.

Also, for different cell types, use different identifiers (you didn't show this code).

The programming guides have good example on table views and their cells and reuse pattern. It's worth reading a couple of times - it's easy to get wrong and is a main topic for performance tuning.

**Edit**

Now that you added more code, another problem seems to be here:

```
if (indexPath.section==1 && indexPath.row==2) {
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}
```

You are missing an `else` part. The `selectionStyle` and `accessoryType` are set to what they were set to before - you miss to configure the cells correctly for all other cells than that special one.

Each cell type should really get its own identifier though. If the adding/removing of subviews work as expected is hard to tell from that code.

One thought: As you aren't really reusing a lot of the cells here anyhow you could even disable the reuse by changing

```
static NSString *kDisplayCell_ID = @"DisplayCellID";
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kDisplayCell_ID];
```

to

```
static NSString *kDisplayCell_ID = nil;
```

This would just always produce a new cell. I wouldn't recommend this in the general case, though.

Comment: +1 - in general all the programming guides are well written and worth reading.

Comment: @Eiko I added the whole code for the method. I actually got used Apple's own sample code as a reference. If I have to add two different subViews on one cell, I take care that they have different tags so that they both get released when off screen. Besides, I don' t have any problem with the subview I add, it is only the disclousure indicator and the tapping background. If I add a bunch of subViews it's because in one row there is a Slider with a label indicating its value, on the next row I only need a textField, etc.

Comment: Now that I checked it again, it doesn't have anything to do with scrolling. It seems it has to do with the array loaded when the view is pushed. When I go back and I push again arrayOne or arrayThree then I see the disclousure on the second and third row. If I push array two, I see disclousures indicators on the three rows.Those arrays contain two NSdictionaries, one for Section==0 and one for section==1. The funny thing is that section==1 is the same for all of them.

Comment: I believe I know where the problem is. It ocurred to me while starting my car's engine to go to work. I hate that. I believe that the conditional statement with the disclosure indicator and tapped background should be right under the allocation of the cell, where the other cell behaviour is declared. Now I'll have to wait 10+ hours to find out if I am correct. Hatting it!

Comment: @Eiko I know the code isn´t very clear, but the subViews work perfectly. Even though it works, I want to rewrite it to be more clear, for me to have as future reference. So, if I understand correctly your answer, the thought it came this morning is about right. Isn´t it?. Could you elaborate what you mean by "one identifier by cell"?

Comment: The reuse pattern gives every cell (type) a name so that cells of the same type can easily be reused, i.e. you pass kDisplayCell_ID here to alloc/init. As you want different types of cells (with disclosure and without) I see no point in sharing the same name and reconfiguring them. Really, check the docs and look in multiple example projects with table views. They are essential, it's a very important topic in iOS programming.

Comment: ... Ah, ok. So that cells that share similar configuration have an unique identifier, right?. I will check the docs, certainly. Thanks.

Comment: As it turns out it seems not to be a problem of the cell, but a problem of the switch triggering the insertion of section==1. Also important to know that I'm adding a footerView either on section==0 or section==1, whatever is on the bottom. I'm adding the code of the switch on my first post.

Comment: I'd actually pay for someone to fix this. Now not only the disclousure indicator is going nuts, I'm too.

Comment: I kind of got it done using a unique identifier for the row with the disclousure indicator. The switch worked allright but when I press the back button and loaded another data for the table, on that row, the title was incorrect, mixed up. I ended up having to release and reallocate the table every time is pushed... But at least it works now somehow.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to `cellReusability`, and it has, for a long time, wasted so many developers' time  and effort. If you knew the concept of cell reusability, you would know that while scrolling, the index of the row and sections remain the same (although you expect it to be different for a different position on the `uiTableView`).

The only way is to `subClass` the `UITableViewCell` and create your own `CustomUITableViewCell`, and implement that with the disclosure indicator, or resist your input to just a small TableView that fits the screen and make `scrollable = NO`.